# Log4php - LoggerAppenderSyslog - set System Information

Tags: php, logging, syslog, log4php

I'm using log4PHP (logger LoggerAppenderSyslog) to log some information in the windows event log. Everything works correctly but I need also to modify the source and the event Id.

In the XML view of the event i need to change the tags "Provider Name" and "EventID"

```html
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="PHP-5.6.8" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="16384">2</EventID> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>6</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-11-13T17:35:26.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>150111</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>xxxxxxx</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>php[8948]</Data> 
  <Data>PROVA2</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Is it possible to do with log4php or I need to use some other mechanism?

Thanks,

Emilio